# How to compile single python scripts (not to exe)?

Tags: python, django

I know there is a lot of debate within this topic.
I made some research, I looked into some of the questions here, but none was exactly it.

I'm developing my app in Django, using Python 3.7 and I'm not looking to convert my app into a single .exe file, actually it wouldn't be reasonable to do so, if even possible.

However, I have seen some apps developed in javascript that use bytenode to compile code to .jsc

Is there such a thing for python? I know there is .pyc, but for all I know those are just runtime compiled files, not actually a bytecode precompiled script.

I wanted to protect the source code on some files that can compromise the security of the app. After all, deploying my app means deploying a fully fledged python installation with a web port open and an app that works on it.

What do you think, is there a way to do it, does it even make sense to you?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precompiled (`.pyc`) files are what you are looking for. They contain pre-optimized bytecode that can be run by the interpreter even when the original `.py` file is absent.

You can build the `.pyc` files directly using `python -m py_compile <filename>`. There is also a more optimized `.pyo` format that further reduces the file size by removing identifier names and docstrings. You can turn it on by using `-OO`.

Note that it might still be possible to decompile the generated bytecode with enough effort, so don't use it as a security measure.

Comment: In deed ou are right. I just don't want to make it plain-text. If someone gives it enough effort to decompile bytecode, there is no way to stop them from decompiling anything else, I guess :/

But there are still some tricks to compensate this, I hope : )

Comment: Note that if you set up your server properly a user should not be able to access the app files and source over HTTP, so the ability to de-compile becomes a non-issue